# Nutch with solr on https

Tags: https, solr, nutch

Good morning, 
I come to you because I have a problem with `Nutch (1.14)` and `Solr (7.2)`

so it works fine until I put SSL in place.

With Solr in http, once the crawl is finished I execute this command

```
bin/nutch index -Dsolr.server.url=http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/CORENAME crawltest/crawldb/ -linkdb crawltest/linkdb/ crawltest/segments/* -filter -normalize -deleteGone
```

And it works very well

However, once SSL is activated and the solr server in HTTPS, it is impossible to send the data to Solr.
I have added in nutch site the following properties

```
<name>solr.auth</name>
           <value>true</value>

<property>
           <name>solr.auth.username</name>
           <value>xxxx</value>

<property>
           <name>solr.auth.password</name>
           <value>xxxx</value>

property>
           <name>solr.server.type</name>
           <value>https</value>
property>
           <name>solr.server.url</name>
           <value>https://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/CORENAME</value>
```

But when I execute the previous command I get an error of this type

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: https://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/CORENAME
```

&

```
caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

&

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Did you succeed in sending the data to a HTTPS solr? 
Thanks

**EDIT**
To fix this errors following SSL procedure https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/enabling-ssl.html

And at the end execute this
`keytool -import -file /path/to/solr/solr-ssl.pem -alias solr_cert -keystore /path/to/java-cacert` (jre/lib/security/cacerts) 
the default password is changeit

Comment: Do you have a valid certificate for localhost/127.0.0.1? The error message seems to tell you that the security layer is unable to verify the authenticity of the certificate the server presented.

Comment: Since you won't get a validated certificate for localhost/127.0.0.1, the certificate / the signing certification probably has to be trusted in your keystore, or you have to tell SunCertPathBuilder to disable certificate checking.

Comment: Good morning, 
Indeed I use a self signed certificate.
I followed the ground documentation procedure [SSL](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/enabling-ssl.html).
I tried with the `-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false` option but still the same error. Have I forgotten something important? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new answer because the previous was too long

**SOLVED API AUTHENTICATION BUT NOT WITH NUTCH:** 
So to make authentication work via the API I deleted the configuration made in `jetty-https.xml`, `webdefault.xml` and I deleted the `realm.properties` file as well as the basic auth options in `solr.in.sh`
I only work on the `security.json` file in SOLR HOME

In fact the biggest problem was that I did not use an encrypted password to test the connection while without it impossible to connect. On the other hand I still have the problem via nutch which is not allowed.

Here is the `security.json` file

```
`{
    "authentication":{
        "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
        "credentials":{
            "solr":"hzMjhfgN4b9X8KR0QgLB2Um3cUzqDzJygtEBL/O7g5E= CkP7HyXjYvqKNF3F4hBjnVvKGQOkLc/ta4FaNIkqgII="
        }
    },
    "authorization":{
        "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
        "permissions":[
            {
                "name":"security-edit",
                "role":"adminRole"
            },
            {
                "name":"collection-admin-edit",
                "role":"adminRole"
            },
            {
                "name":"update",
                "role":"adminRole"
            },
            {
                "name":"config-edit",
                "role":"adminRole"
            },
            {
                "name":"core-admin-edit",
                "role":"adminRole"
            },
            {
                "name":"core-admin-read",
                "role":"adminRole"
            {
                "name":"schema-edit",
                "role":"adminRole"
            },
            {
                "name":"all",
                "role":"adminRole"
            }
        ],
        "user-role":{
            "solr":"adminRole"
        }
    }
}
`
```

The encrypted password represented value "test"

To test the file code i suggest this http://json.parser.online.fr/

What could I have missed to be able to update solr with nutch?

**SOLVED** 
Add in update role path for dataimport

```
           {
                "name":"update",
                "path":"/dataimport",
                "role":"adminRole"
            },
```

But now i can index nutch to solr but i have a new error when i'm crawling...

```
`Thu Jun 28 09:21:03 CEST 2018 : Iteration 2 of 5
Generating a new segment
/app/nutch-external/bin/nutch generate -D mapreduce.job.reduces=2 -D mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1000m -D mapreduce.reduce.speculative=false -D mapreduce.map.speculative=false -D mapreduce.map.output.compress=true crawl//crawldb crawl//segments -topN 50000 -numFetchers 1 -noFilter
Generator: starting at 2018-06-28 09:21:04
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
Generator: filtering: false
Generator: normalizing: true
Generator: topN: 50000
Generator: 0 records selected for fetching, exiting ...
Generate returned 1 (no new segments created)
Escaping loop: no more URLs to fetch now
`
```

And during the first Iteration i have this errors

```
`Authorization challenge processed
No form element found with 'id' = adminRole, trying 'name'.
No form element found with 'id' = adminRole, trying 'name'.
No form element found with 'name' = adminRole
No form element found with 'name' = adminRole
Supported authentication schemes in the order of preference: [ntlm, digest, basic]
Supported authentication schemes in the order of preference: [ntlm, digest, basic]
Challenge for ntlm authentication scheme not available
Challenge for ntlm authentication scheme not available
Challenge for digest authentication scheme not available
basic authentication scheme selected
Using authentication scheme: basic
Authorization challenge processed
No form element found with 'id' = adminRole, trying 'name'.
No form element found with 'name' = adminRole
Failed to get protocol output
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No form exists: adminRole
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.httpclient.Http.resolveCredentials(Http.java:506)
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.httpclient.Http.getResponse(Http.java:183)
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.api.HttpBase.getProtocolOutput(HttpBase.java:276)
    at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherThread.run(FetcherThread.java:342)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No form exists: adminRole
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.httpclient.HttpFormAuthentication.getLoginFormParams(HttpFormAuthentication.java:219)
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.httpclient.HttpFormAuthentication.login(HttpFormAuthentication.java:95)
    at org.apache.nutch.protocol.httpclient.Http.resolveCredentials(Http.java:504)
    ... 3 more
Challenge for digest authentication scheme not available
basic authentication scheme selected
Using authentication scheme: basic
Authorization challenge processed
No form element found with 'id' = adminRole, trying 'name'.
`
```

It's still `security.json` file. Have you any ideas ? thanks

**SOLVED** 
I solved this by configure `httpclient-auth.xml` in `/nutch/conf/`

```
<auth-configuration>
   <credentials username="solr" password="xxxxx">
      <authscope host="localhost" port="8983"/>
   </credentials>
</auth-configuration>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

it advances a little, once the certificate import in cacerts I do not have any more this error.

Still in the same context, after activating SSL and authentication on the solr server. I use Nutch to Crawl the urls and send the data to solr. 
Since the implementation of SSL I can no longer send data to SOLR.

When i execute `this bin/nutch index -Dsolr.server.url=https://localhost:8983/solr/CORE -Dsolr.auth=true  -Dsolr.auth.username='solr'  -Dsolr.auth.password='xxxx' crawltest/crawldb/ -linkdb crawltest/linkdb/ crawltest/segments/* -filter -normalize -deleteGone`

I have the following two errors:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr/CORE: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/CORE/update. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr/CORE: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/CORE/update. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT :** 
The first error is due to an authentication error.
After filling in the right values, I have a new error that I don't understand.. Do you have any ideas?

```
2018-06-20 09:47:18,116 INFO  regex.RegexURLNormalizer - can't find rules for scope 'indexer', using default
2018-06-20 09:47:19,151 INFO  indexer.IndexWriters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter
2018-06-20 09:47:19,194 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: content dest: content
2018-06-20 09:47:19,194 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: title dest: title
2018-06-20 09:47:19,194 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: host dest: host
2018-06-20 09:47:19,194 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: segment dest: segment
2018-06-20 09:47:19,194 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: boost dest: boost
2018-06-20 09:47:19,195 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: digest dest: digest
2018-06-20 09:47:19,195 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: tstamp dest: tstamp
2018-06-20 09:47:19,525 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 250/250 documents
2018-06-20 09:47:19,525 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Deleting 0 documents
2018-06-20 09:47:19,808 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 250/250 documents
2018-06-20 09:47:19,809 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Deleting 0 documents
2018-06-20 09:47:19,951 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local146539832_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.makeIOException(SolrIndexWriter.java:234)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.push(SolrIndexWriter.java:213)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.write(SolrIndexWriter.java:174)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.write(IndexWriters.java:87)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:50)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$3.collect(ReduceTask.java:422)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:369)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: https://localhost:8983/solr/ESRF-EXTERNAL
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:589)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:229)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1219)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.push(SolrIndexWriter.java:210)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:886)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:857)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:181)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity.writeTo(InputStreamEntity.java:146)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:203)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:481)
    ... 20 more
2018-06-20 09:47:20,873 ERROR indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:873)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:147)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:239)
```

**Stacktrace**

```
name    cpuTime / userTime

process reaper (37)
java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@24197386
    1.8587ms
0.0000ms

process reaper (36)
java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@24197386
    1.2672ms
0.0000ms

Scheduler-201556483 (31) java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@6202c0c1
    1.1534ms
0.0000ms

searcherExecutor-7-thread-1 (30)   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@663d5859
    63.2030ms
50.0000ms

DestroyJavaVM (27)
    1164.4748ms
1040.0000ms

Thread-12 (25)
java.lang.Object@233fcafa
    0.1211ms
0.0000ms

Connection evictor (23)
    0.9319ms
0.0000ms

Connection evictor (22)
    2.0995ms
0.0000ms

org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@1a052a00Timer (21)    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@6626f9cf
    4.2127ms
0.0000ms

qtp2012232625-20 (20)   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@12d62902
    56.7955ms
50.0000ms

qtp2012232625-19 (19)
    47.6864ms
40.0000ms

qtp2012232625-18 (18) java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@12d62902
    79.3320ms
70.0000ms

qtp2012232625-17 (17)   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@12d62902
    100.9593ms
90.0000ms

qtp2012232625-16-acceptor-0@2d033cc4-ServerConnector@23c4c714{SSL,[ssl, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8983} (16)
    4.5898ms
0.0000ms

qtp2012232625-15 (15)    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@12d62902
    73.3096ms
60.0000ms

qtp2012232625-14 (14)    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@12d62902
    18.7950ms
10.0000ms

qtp2012232625-13 (13)
    79.7804ms
70.0000ms

qtp2012232625-12 (12)
    70.2385ms
60.0000ms

qtp2012232625-11 (11)    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@12d62902
    22.1012ms
10.0000ms

ShutdownMonitor (10)
    0.3055ms
0.0000ms

Signal Dispatcher (5)
    0.0873ms
0.0000ms

Finalizer (3)    
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@1e254491
    8.2575ms
0.0000ms

Reference Handler (2)    
java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock@431035b5
    6.3846ms
0.0000ms
```

**EDIT2**
To test I disabled authentication to see if the problem did not come from https. Without authentication it works! 
I tried to change the file and include it in jetty-https.xml rather than jetty.xml.

I have 2 account configure like this

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Solr authenticated application</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

security.json

```
{
"authentication":{
   "blockUnknown": true,
   "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
   "credentials":{"solr":"xxxx"}
},
"authorization":{
   "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
   "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",
      "role":"admin"}],
   "user-role":{"solr":"admin"}
}}
```

when i execute the following command

```
bin/nutch index -Dsolr.server.url=https://localhost:8983/solr/MYCORE -Dsolr.auth=true  -Dsolr.auth.username='admin'  -Dsolr.auth.password='xxxx' crawltest/crawldb/ -linkdb crawltest/linkdb/ crawltest/segments/* -filter -normalize -deleteGone
```

and I get this error

```
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
        at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.makeIOException(SolrIndexWriter.java:234)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.push(SolrIndexWriter.java:213)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.write(SolrIndexWriter.java:174)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.write(IndexWriters.java:87)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:50)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:41)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:493)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$3.collect(ReduceTask.java:422)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:369)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: https://localhost:8983/solr/MYCORE
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:589)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:240)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:229)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1219)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.push(SolrIndexWriter.java:210)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
        at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
        at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:886)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:857)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:181)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
        at org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity.writeTo(InputStreamEntity.java:146)
        at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:112)
        at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:203)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:481)
       ... 20 more
2018-06-25 09:38:41,870 ERROR indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:873)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:147)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:230)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:239)
```

And when i execute this

```
bin/nutch index -Dsolr.server.url=https://localhost:8983/solr/MYCORE -Dsolr.auth=true  -Dsolr.auth.username='solr'  -Dsolr.auth.password='xxxxx' crawltest/crawldb/ -linkdb crawltest/linkdb/ crawltest/segments/* -filter -normalize -deleteGone
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr/MYCORE: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/MYCORE/update. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre></p>
</body>
</html>

        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr/MYCORE: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/MYCORE/update. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:544)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:240)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:229)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1219)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.push(SolrIndexWriter.java:210)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.write(SolrIndexWriter.java:174)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.write(IndexWriters.java:87)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:50)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:41)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:493)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$3.collect(ReduceTask.java:422)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:369)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-06-25 09:45:20,106 ERROR indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:873)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:147)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:230)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:239)
```

or now this :

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at https://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/MYCORE: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 503 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 503</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/MYCORE/update. Reason:
<pre>    Service Unavailable</pre></p>
<hr />
</body>
</html>

        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at https://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/MYCORE: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 503 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 503</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/MYCORE/update. Reason:
<pre>    Service Unavailable</pre></p>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Solr logs :

```
2018-06-25 14:18:44.352 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server jetty-9.3.20.v20170531
2018-06-25 14:18:44.597 WARN  (main) [   ] o.e.j.w.WebAppContext Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@5891e32e{/solr,file:///app/solr-7.2.1/server/solr-webapp/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/app/solr-7.2.1/server/solr-webapp/webapp}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoginService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator@64c87930 in org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@400cff1a
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.setConfiguration(LoginAuthenticator.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:448)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:809)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:458)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1520)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1442)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:215)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:458)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:76)
2018-06-25 14:18:44.745 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server Started @799ms
```

**I Solved "No LoginService" by move the security.json on /var/solr/data/ (SOLR_HOME)**

**EDIT3:** 
now I only get an error message "No allow" when I want to send nutch data to solr. Also I can no longer connect to the admin interface I get the same error. I think it came from the security.json file

```
{
"authentication":{
   "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
   "credentials":{"solr":"xxxxxx"}
},
"authorization":{
   "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin"
   "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit","role":"adminRole"},{"name":"collection-admin-edit","role":"adminRole"},{"name":"update","role":"adminRole"},{"name":"all","role":"adminRole"},{"name":"core-admin-edit","role":"adminRole"},{"name":"read","role":"adminRole"},{"name":"config-edit","role":"adminRole"},{"name":"core-admin-read","role":"adminRole"},{"name":"core-admin-read","role":"adminRole"}]
   "user-role":{"solr":"adminRole"}
}}
```

What did I do wrong? thanks

Comment: Please edit your question with further details about your problem - do not post them as an answer.

Comment: Your new error is a different problem, so edit the answer to include how you imported the certificates into cacerts and post that as an answer you accept, then create a new question about failing authentication (.. which is caused by wrong user/password - either missing in the request or not being configured to the same value in Solr.

Comment: yes I already edited my first post to add the solution. 
The problem appears when SSL is enabled that's why I haven't opened a new topic
I have two account for solr authentication and the problem appears with both too.

Comment: so, i think i found the real user. with the first i have unauthorized (All right, normal) but with the second i'm authorized but I fall into the second problem : 
`Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)`
what is this?

Comment: That's impossible to say without having the actual stacktrace -- possibly on the server side as well.

Comment: Not any ideas ?

Comment: What does your server log say about the connection attempt?

Comment: Then the question becomes wether you've successfully authenticated with the user you've added to your `security.json` file - since you no longer can access the admin interface, it sounds like the file is blocking access.

Comment: Indeed I am not authorized as soon as the file `security.json` is in place.
I try to configure with user solr in this same file, or with user admin which is configured in `/etc/realm.properties` but I get the same error. 
Yet the `all` option in the `security.json` file should let me pass no?